# Que significa el siguiente icono amarillo en Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

En mi proyecto Java con Eclipse, me e dado cuenta que junto al icono de cada clase aparece un icono en forma de cilindro? Quisiera saber cual es el significado de dicho icono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Indica los archivos que están siendo trackeados por el sistema de versionamiento, los que no tienen el símbolo no lo están. Saludos.

Comment: Seguramente has descargado tu proyecto de subversion o de algún servidor y lo has sincronizado posteriormente. Te sale ese icono si está online el archivo y con un signo de interrogación azul si no existe el archivo en el servidor.

Comment: Puedas que tengas configurado el control de versionado en tu proyecto. Eclipse trae por defecto el versionado con la herramineta [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) Aqui te dejo la documentacion de eclipse relacionada https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/index.jsp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cuando utilizas un sistema de control de versiones, como Subversion o Git, el proyecto se guarda en un repositorio (servidor), normalmente diferente del computador donde se desarrolla el propio proyecto.

Cuando te conectas a ese repositorio y descargas un proyecto para modificarlo (en este caso mediante el IDE Eclipse), se crea una copia local de sus ficheros (normalmente todos) en tu computadora.

Entonces puedes realizar modificaciones en tu copia local del proyecto, y posteriormente, cuando todo está correcto, subir tus cambios al repositorio.

Esto permite el trabajo colaborativo en paralelo, puesto que dos programadores pueden modificar partes diferentes de sus copias locales del proyecto en diferentes computadoras, para más tarde subir sus cambios al repositorio y sincronizarse con él.

Ahora bien, el símbolo que comentas (el cilindro amarillo) aparece cuando la copia local de un fichero está en la misma versión que el fichero del repositorio, es decir, se ha descargado la última versión de ese fichero del repositorio y no has realizado cambios en la copia local, por lo que se dice que el fichero "está sincronizado" o bien que está en su última versión del repositorio.

Como apunte final, en eclipse, cuando modificas un fichero de tu copia local del proyecto, el cilindro amarillo se cambia por un asterisco, indicando que los cambios en ese fichero aún no han sido subidos al repositorio.

Otro caso es cuando creas un fichero nuevo en el proyecto en local, es decir, aún no existe en el repositorio. En ese caso, aparece un símbolo de interrogación azul, indicando que es un fichero que solo existe en tu máquina, por lo que habrá que subirlo al repositorio para que el resto del equipo tenga acceso a él.